# Need to resolve an SQL query error

Tags: sql

```
CREATE TABLE DEPARTMENTS
   (    DEPARTMENT_ID NUMERIC(4,0), 
    "DEPARTMENT_NAME" VARCHAR(30 ) CONSTRAINT DEPT_NAME_NN NOT NULL , 
    "MANAGER_ID" NUMERIC(6,0), 
    "LOCATION_ID" NUMERIC(4,0), 
   );


  CREATE TABLE EMPLOYEES 
   (    EMPLOYEE_ID NUMERIC(6,0), 
    FIRST_NAME VARCHAR(20 ), 
    LAST_NAME VARCHAR(25 ) CONSTRAINT "EMP_LAST_NAME_NN" NOT NULL , 
    EMAIL VARCHAR(25 ) CONSTRAINT "EMP_EMAIL_NN" NOT NULL , 
    PHONE_NUMBER VARCHAR(20 ), 
    HIRE_DATE DATE CONSTRAINT "EMP_HIRE_DATE_NN" NOT NULL , 
    JOB_ID VARCHAR(10 ) CONSTRAINT "EMP_JOB_NN" NOT NULL , 
    SALARY NUMERIC(8,2), 
    COMMISSION_PCT NUMERIC(2,2), 
    MANAGER_ID NUMERIC(6,0), 
    DEPARTMENT_ID NUMERIC(4,0), 

   );
```

I need to list the name of the department, average salary and number of employees working in that department who got commission.

```
SELECT DEPARTMENT_NAME, AVG(SALARY), COUNT(COMMISSION_PCT) 
FROM DEPARTMENTS  JOIN EMPLOYEES  USING (DEPARTMENT_ID); 

GROUP BY DEPARTMENT_NAME
```

This is what I've got so far, but it gives me an error:

> "DEPARTMENT_ID" is not a recognized table hints option. If it is intended as a parameter to a table-valued function or to the CHANGETABLE function, ensure that your database compatibility mode is set to 90.

Comment: Remove the semicolon after `USING (DEPARTMENT_ID)`, and put it after the `GROUP BY` clause, at the end of your query.

Comment: Tag with the database you are using.  Is it Oracle?

Comment: still the same error

Comment: I am studying this in database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know which *DBMS* did you use.

I think that will be work,when you use `INNER JOIN` instead of `USING`

```
SELECT DEPARTMENT_NAME, AVG(SALARY), COUNT(COMMISSION_PCT) 
FROM DEPARTMENTS 
INNER JOIN EMPLOYEES on DEPARTMENTS.DEPARTMENT_ID = EMPLOYEES.DEPARTMENT_ID
GROUP BY DEPARTMENT_NAME;
```